# Enabling Intellisense for Custom Sections in .config Files

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, intellisense, app-config

When editing .NET config files (app.config, web.config, etc) in Visual Studio, I get Visual Studio's intellisense to guide me when choosing my application's settings. If I add a custom configuration section, how can I enable intellisense for my custom settings? I'm sure there must be an easy answer to this, but a cursory Google search didn't give me any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you do not want to modify your Visual Studio files or copy anything into the Visual Studio folder, you can add the `.xsd` file to your project, open your `.config` file and select *Schemas* in the *Properties* window (click the `[…]` icon):

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio showing where to find and change the "Schemas" property of your <code>.config</code> file]

Comment: +1 The accepted solution seems widely practiced, but you shouldn't do this unless the schema changes are standard and useful to all the Visual Studio projects that may be created on your computer.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx)

Answer (score 35):

As the other answers say, you need to provide an XML Schema document for your custom configuration section. There's no need to add the `.xsd` schema file to some global directory; you can reference it directly from your custom section in the `App.config` file:

```
<configuration>

  <!-- make the custom section known to .NET's configuration manager -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="customSection" type="..." />
  </configSections>

  <!-- your custom section -->
  <customSection xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customSection.xsd"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customSection.xsd">
    ...
  </customSection>

<configuration>
```

The `xmlns` attribute is merely there to set a default namespace, so that you don't need to set it on your `customSection` element and all of its child elements. (However, do not place the `xmlns` attribute on the `<configuration>` element!)

The `customSection.xsd` contains the schema that will be used by IntelliSense, for example:

```
<xs:schema id="customSectionSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/customSection.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customSection.xsd"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/customSection.xsd"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="customSection">
    ...
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: What TYPE am I supposed to put in section.type?  I guessed and put "xmlns" in there and it works...but I'm pretty sure that's wrong.

Comment: @Prisoner, you're supposed to put a (at least assembly-qualified) .NET type name à la `"Namespace.Class, Assembly"` there. The framework will instantiate this type and use it whenever it wants to parse the custom configuration section. Choose any of a few pre-defined section handler classes, or any custom class that implements the `IConfigurationSectionHandler` interface. For further info, google for something like `"App.config custom section handlers"`, or read an article on the topic such as [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ConfigSections.aspx) to get started.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but this seems to cause runtime problem when the Configuration Manager tries to read the custom config section and it could not recognize the `xmlns:xsi` attribute. Do you know what I can do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Frank: I've noticed these kinds of problems, too. Did you put the `xmlns:xsi` attribute on your custom section's element, or on an ancestor element (such as `<configuration>`)? The latter will very likely cause problems.

Comment: @stakx, I had the `xmlns:xsi` on the section element, like your example. And I have the `.xsd` included in my project. It seems to work now (both Intellisense and runtime read) *after* I removed the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attributes and just leave the `xmlns` attribute.

Comment: @Frank: That is strange. I don't know what's up with that, but glad to hear you got things working. Thank you for commenting on this issue!

Answer (score 11):

You need to create an XSD file for your custom settings and copy it to the schema directory of your visual Studio install. For 2005, this is: %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\XML\Schemas

Here some information on this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/how-to-configure-the-visual-studio-2005-ide-to-use-custom-xsd-files-for-intellisense