# Intellisense for custom config section problem with namespaces

Tags: .net, intellisense, configurationsection

I have just rolled a custom configuration section, created an accompanying schema document for Intellisense and added it to the Web.config's Schemas property as per [Michael Stum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742905/enabling-intellisense-for-custom-sections-in-config-files/2044410#2044410) to another similar question.

Unfortunately, and possibly due to me creating the XSD by hand with limited knowledge, the Intellisense relies on an `xmlns` attribute pointing to my XSD file's namespace being present in the custom config element. However, when running the project I get an **Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive** error.

I could probably just modify my XSD file to define the `xmlns` attribute for that element, however I am wondering if this is just a bandaid fix to a larger problem. I must confess I don't have a very good understanding of XML namespaces so this might be an oppportunity to set me straight on a few things.

Here is the attributes for my XSD file's root `xs:schema` element:

```
<xs:schema id="awesomeConfig"
           targetNamespace="http://awesome.com/schemas"
           xmlns="http://awesome.com/schemas"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

And on creating the element in the Web.config file, Visual Studio 2008 automatically appends:

```
<awesomeConfig xmlns="http://awesome.com/schemas"></awesomeConfig>
```

So have I misunderstood the meaning of the `xs:schema` attributes at all, or is the proper solution as simple as it seems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your schema will need to omit the `targetNamespace` attribute. In effect, this will put the schema contents into the default namespace.

That's necessary because the .NET configuration system has never permitted elements to be in a namespace.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the consequence of this is that I must avoid naming clashes? If so, how would I implement the standard collection elements of add/remove/clear?

Comment: Those standard elements are not a naming clash if you use the same syntax. Also, the schema will be relative to the parent elements. If you make the root of your schema be your configuration section name, then there will be no name conflicts, as long as your schema is strictly hierarchical. Make the add/remove/clear elements child elements of their parent instead of global elements referenced later.