# Custom web.config sections (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Apologies in advance for the relatively long post - I've tried to provide as much  relevant information as I can (including code listings)!

I've been working on implementing a custom section in the web.config file for a little something I'm working for the past few hours, but I can't seem to get it working. The following is what I'd like to use as my XML structure:

```
<mvcmodules>
    <module moduleAlias="name" type="of.type">
        <properties>
            <property name="propname" value="propvalue" />
        </properties>
    </module>
</mvcmodules>
```

Currently, I have the following classes set up and working (somewhat):

- ModuleSection
- ModuleCollection
- Module
- ModulePropertyCollection
- ModuleProperty

The only way I can see to get close to the way I want to do this is to wrap my  declarations in another parent called . However, when I do this, I get an error if I have more than one instance of the  tag ("The element  may only appear once in this section."), and with one  tag, the information is not being read in to the objects.

I've written a little basic documentation so you can get an idea of how I'm structuring this and hopefully see where I'm going wrong

**ModuleSection**
This class holds a ModulesCollection object

```
namespace ASPNETMVCMODULES.Configuration
{
    public class ModulesSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("modules", IsRequired = true)]
    public ModuleCollection Modules
    {
        get
        {
            return this["modules"] as ModuleCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

**ModulesCollection**
Holds a collection of Module objects

```
namespace ASPNETMVCMODULES.Configuration
{
public class ModuleCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("module")]
    public Module this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as Module;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }

            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Module();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Module)element).ModuleAlias;
    }
}
```

}

**Module** 
Contains information about the module and a ModulePropertyCollection object

```
    public class Module : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("moduleAlias", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ModuleAlias
    {
        get
        {
            return this["moduleAlias"] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ModuleType
    {
        get
        {
            return this["type"] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("properties")]
    public ModulePropertyCollection ModuleProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return this["properties"] as ModulePropertyCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

**ModulePropertyCollection**
Contains a collection of ModuleProperty objects

```
    public class ModulePropertyCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ModuleProperty this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as ModuleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }

            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ModuleProperty();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ModuleProperty)element).Name;
    }
}
```

**ModuleProperty**
Holds information about the module properties

```
    public class ModuleProperty : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this["name"] as string;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this["value"] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create a property decorated with the [ConfigurationCollectionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx) attribute. I scanned your code and didn't see a reference to it anywhere.

The MSDN link for once actually has a useful example. I recently put together a custom config section myself, and found that page entirely adequate. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986439/intellisense-for-custom-config-section-problem-with-namespaces) for how to enable Intellisense support for your config section in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ah, very good. Thank you very much, good sir! Worked a treat. First time too!