# Not getting VS2013 Intellisense for custom config even with schema defined

Tags: c#, intellisense, custom-configuration

I have custom config section which I can read correctly. Now I wanted Intellisense for it.

I have created my schema by first creating an XML with only my config section, and then got VS2013 to generate the Schema file for me. Named it `CustomConfig.xsd` and added to my project. I updated the schema based on @stakx's answer in [this SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742905/enabling-intellisense-for-custom-sections-in-config-files/), so it looks like this:

```
<xs:schema id="customConfigSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/customConfig.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customConfig.xsd"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/customConfig.xsd"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="customConfig">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="someElement">
          <xs:complexType>
            ...
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        ...
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then in my `app.config` I added the schema details to `<customConfig>`, like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
    <section name="customConfig" type="..." />
  </configSections>
  ...
  <customConfig xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customConfig.xsd" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customConfig.xsd">
    <someElement ... />
  </customConfig>
</configuration>
```

Saved everything, then I tried to test it by editing `<someElement>`, but there is no Intellisense. What am I missing?

I can see that when I open my `app.config` and view the Property Window, the Schemas show my schema file as ticked. So I can only assume it is picking up the schema attribute from my `app.config`. Yet no Intellisense.

**UPDATE**

I just realised I do not get Intellisense at all on my `app.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened my solution on VS2015, and it gives me Intellisense on my custom config.

Then I noticed on my VS2013, for some reason, does not use the `DotNetConfig.xsd` by default. This was not the case on VS2015. When I ticked it on VS2013 so it is used, Intellisense for my custom config started working.